# Real analysis, The limits of two related sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently working on som of the exercises in Abbot's Understanding Analysis, and I have gotten stuck on an exercise. The exercise is as follows:

If $(x_{n})\rightarrow x$, show that $\sqrt{(x_{n})}\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$

I have been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate some help.

I have tried using the definition of that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, $\forall\epsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: n\geq N\Rightarrow |x_{n}-x|<\epsilon$, but I can't find a proper way to manipulate this expression to get $|\sqrt{x_{n}}-\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove (or assert) that

$$
\left|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right| \leq \sqrt{\left|x - y\right|}.
$$

It may be easier (more intuitive) to first prove, for positive $a$, $b$,

$$
a + b \leq (\sqrt a + \sqrt b)^2
$$
which implies 
$$
\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt a + \sqrt b.
$$

Answer (score 0):

How about some nonstandard analysis. Let $H$ be an infinite [Hyperreal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) number.
$x_H\approx x$ (meaning they are infinitely close.) Now we must show that $\sqrt{x_H}\approx \sqrt x$. We know that $x-x_H \approx 0$.

$$(x-x_h)^2\approx0$$
$$x^2-2x*x_H+x_h^2\approx0$$
$$x^2+2x*x_H+x_H^2\approx4x*x_H$$
$$x+x_H\approx2\sqrt{x*x_H}$$
$$x-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x_H}+x_H\approx0$$
and
$$(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_h})^2=x-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x_H}+x_H$$
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_h})^2\approx0$$
$$\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_H}\approx0$$
$$\sqrt x \approx \sqrt{x_H}$$
End of proof

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can use the fact that $$\sqrt x_n -\sqrt x = \frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x}.$$ And apply the logic you have written down in your second last sentence. If you need further elaboration let me know.